# Error MT2002 in xamarin studio (Monotouch)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Good day ,

I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 (build 3) for my iOS app , but I unable to build app to device or iOS simulator due to an error :

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void MonoTouch.Foundation.FieldAttribute::.ctor(System.String,System.String)" reference from "monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065

When I change ' Linker Behaviour ' to ' Link SDK assembly only ' that error occur , but if I change to ' Don't Link ' every thing work great , but app size will change from 23mb to 60mb .

Thx

Comment: The `[Field]` attribute is recent but you need to tell us your **Xamarin.iOS** version (not Xamarin Studio version). The easiest way to get exact version information (for all producst) is to use the "Xamarin Studio" menu, "About Xamarin Studio" item, "Show Details" button and copy/paste the version informations (you can use the "Copy Information" button).

Comment: @poupou 
Version: 6.2.3.0 (Business Edition)
Hash: 8d98f5e
Branch: 
Build date: 2013-10-04 14:08:06-0400

Answer (score 2):

The `[Field]` attribute was added in 6.2.6 ([see API diff from release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/api_changes/from_6.2.5_to_6.2.6)).

This means you're using an assembly binary (e.g. bindings) that was compiled with 6.2.6+ and it not compatible with earlier versions of Xamarin.iOS.

You can either try to get an older version of that assembly or update to 6.2.6 (or a more recent version) of Xamarin.iOS.