# xamarin build pass on simulator but fails on real device

Tags: ios, exception, xamarin

I am creating an app using xamarin to be cross plateform. My android version works well on a simulator and a real device. The ios version works only in the simulator. When I try to debug on a real device I get this error

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod" reference from "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002)

with noting more...

Comment: Perhaps this can solve your issue [Error MT2002 in xamarin studio (Monotouch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290115/error-mt2002-in-xamarin-studio-monotouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue appeared, since I added reference to WebSocket4Net in my PCL project. As the android app was still working, and also the Iphone simulator, I assumed that everything was ok.

I figured out that there are specific binaries or WebSocket4Net for Android and Ios. So I simply added reference to the WebSocket4Net nuget package in the IOS project, and the app works now on my device also.

Thank you for you help and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Xamarin.iOS limitations: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/

> Since the iPhone's kernel prevents an application from generating code
>   dynamically Mono on the iPhone does not support any form of dynamic
>   code generation.
>
> These include: The System.Reflection.Emit is not available.

Comment: @talanta Please accept the answer if it helped you. Accepting helpful answers increases the chances of people helping you in the future.

Comment: thank you @trydis, actually i figured out I needed to add a specific reference to my ios project. I provided the solution to my  issue